# opencv header file not found <opencv/cv.hpp>

Tags: c++, opencv, homebrew

I have a Computer Vision c++ project which uses CMAKE. I am using macOS and since I didn't wanted to install Xcode so
I just did

```
brew install opencv
```

which install opencv but gave me this warning

```
openblas is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because macOS provides BLAS in Accelerate.framework.

For compilers to find openblas you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openblas/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openblas/include"

For pkg-config to find openblas you may need to set:
  export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/openblas/lib/pkgconfig"

==> glib
Bash completion has been installed to:
  /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d
```

now when I run `cmake .` in my project directory it builds the files correctly but when I run `make` it gives me this error

```
n file included from /Users/Osho/Desktop/DIP/Code_Chinese/main.cpp:3:
/Users/Osho/Desktop/DIP/Code_Chinese/SaliencyDetect.h:5:10: fatal error: 
      'opencv/cv.hpp' file not found
#include <opencv/cv.hpp>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/SaliencyDetection.dir/main.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/SaliencyDetection.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Oshos-MacBook-Air-334:Code_Chinese Osho$
```

Please help me in correcting this.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with your cmake file

Comment: `opencv/cv.hpp` is part of the obsolete C API, which has been deprecated for many years and is no longer present in OpenCV 4.x.

Comment: What is the solution Dan?

Comment: Downgrade OpenCV to a version that still contains the deprecated parts (3.x or older), or rewrite your application to use the C++ API.

Comment: I can't thank you enough Dan for giving the insight.

I found the `cv.hpp` file from older opencv version 2.4.9 then copied all header files in `cv.hpp` file into my application and it worked like a charm. I am so happy now. :)